# Finding the probability density function of a random variable using characteristic function.

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

#### Question

Let X be a random variable with characteristic function $\varphi$. Show that

$$
\mathbb{P}(X = a ) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^T e^{-ita}\varphi(t)dt.
$$

#### Attempt

Let $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X<x)$; and $\varphi(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$

By Levy's inversion formula:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=a)  = \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} F(a+\epsilon)-F(a)= 
$$

$$
=\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2 \pi} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-T}^{T}\frac{e^{-i(a+\epsilon)t}-e^{-iat}}{it}\varphi(t)dt=
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon \int_{-T}^{T}e^{-iat}\frac{e^{-\epsilon t}-1}{\epsilon it}\varphi(t)dt
$$

But then I don't know what to do. Can you give me any suggestions please? Thank you

Comment: Hint: Try Fubini's Theorem

Comment: @S.L. Thank you for the insight. Here's what I did, but I'm still not sure what should I do next...
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \epsilon \int_{-T}^T e^{-ita} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{it(x-\epsilon)}-e^{itx}}{-it \epsilon}dF(x) dt
$$

Comment: Is it helpful for the $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ to be be brought outside of the innermost integral cancelling out the multiplication by $\epsilon$ and simplifying(?) the expressions inside the limits?

Comment: @QMath I had an idea of pulling limit of epsilon goes to zero inside the integral and justifying it by some convergence theorem and then the expression in the innermost integral becomes the derivative of $e^{itx}$. Although it might not be a good idea because I'll still have this uncancelled $\epsilon$